# Error with Mysql Group query

Tags: php, mysql

I have some code to get a group of results from mysql, please see below,

```
SELECT string, COUNT(string) as myCount 
FROM ip_stats WHERE string != '' OR string IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY string 
ORDER BY myCount DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Now this code works perfectly, however when i add another where clause as below it returns the same results and seems to be completley ignoring the member = section of the where claus?

```
SELECT string, COUNT(string) as myCount 
FROM ip_stats WHERE member_id = '000826' string != '' OR string IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY string 
ORDER BY myCount DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Any ideas or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't make sense, so I think it may not be what you want:

```
WHERE string != '' OR string IS NOT NULL
```

`string IS NOT NULL` will return all non-null values (including '').

I'm guessing that you want to exclude both empty string ***and*** null string values, in which case this is probably the query you want:

```
SELECT string, COUNT(string) as myCount 
FROM ip_stats 
WHERE member_id = '000826' 
AND string IS NOT NULL 
AND string != '' 
GROUP BY string 
ORDER BY myCount DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 2):

you have some mistakes on your where clause:

```
WHERE member_id = '000826' string != '' OR string IS NOT NULL
```

should probably be

```
WHERE member_id = '000826' AND (string != '' OR string IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [AND-part has priority over the OR-part](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html). Put parentheses to solve this:

```
SELECT string, COUNT(string) as myCount 
FROM ip_stats 
WHERE member_id = '000826' 
AND (string != '' OR string IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY string 
ORDER BY myCount DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

What you were writing actually gave this, which was not what you wanted:

```
WHERE (member_id = '000826' AND string != '')
OR string IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great however i am now back to my original problem, which is when it is grouping the results, the first result is blank which is still getting pulled from the database.  I had managed to stop that but now it seems to have re appeared.